# How to install new version of Netbeans without lost project data?

Tags: updates, netbeans

I'm using Netbeans 7.1.1. Yesterday I checked Netbeans new version and got 7.1.2 version. Then I want to update Netbeans to version 7.1.2, but Netbeans doesn't auto detect previous version and remove it before install. And I don't wanna lose current projects data too! How to install Netbeans new version with remove previous version and keep projects data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per-project data is stored in a separate directory for each project; by default this directory is `.netbeans` directly inside the project root, but it's customizable. Uninstalling the previous version does not touch any of this data so no problem there.

Configuration applicable to NetBeans itself goes into your home directory by default; the uninstaller gives you the option of *not* deleting that, so *do not* check "NetBeans user directory" when uninstalling and you should be fine.